# How to force an Azure DevOps pipeline to fail if any previous tasks have failed?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-tasks

My YAML-based Azure DevOps pipeline contains several tasks in which [`continueOnError: true`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#task-control-options). I did this deliberately so that I can run *all* test suites even when some of them fail (each task runs a different suite of tests). At the moment the build is marked as 'partially succeeded' if any of these tasks fail. Now how do I force the build to be marked as 'failed' instead?

I could probably do this manually by setting a build variable in each task if it fails, and then checking the value of this variable in a final step. But what's the easiest way to force a build to fail if any of the previous steps in the pipeline have failed?

Comment: On release -> Run on agent -> Run this job "Only when all previous jobs have succeeded". This option ***may*** prevent you to deploy the built application if it's partially succeeded

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have any releases, only a pipeline.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Adding one of these tasks to the end of each job seems to do the trick:

```
- bash: |
    echo AGENT_JOBSTATUS = $AGENT_JOBSTATUS
    if [[ "$AGENT_JOBSTATUS" == "SucceededWithIssues" ]]; then exit 1; fi
  displayName: Fail build if partially successful
```

The `echo` line is optional. See the Azure docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agent-variables-devops-services) re the agent variable called `Agent.JobStatus` and the values it can take.

Or you can use Azure's built-in [conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to check the variable directly:

```
- bash: exit 1
  displayName: Fail build if partially successful
  condition: eq(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'SucceededWithIssues')
```

Making the [bash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops) task return any non-zero value will cause it to fail when the `condition` is met.

Comment: can we also fail our pipeline based on output value from previous task?

Comment: @shivam Probably! I recommend you post that as a separate question with more details;. E.g, are you using a `bash` task? You could probably use [`task.setvariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-job-scoped-variable-from-a-script) to set a variable to the output of some command and then set `condition` of a later task to fail the pipeline based on the value of that variable.